# Does shape parameter = degrees of freedom for Student's $t$ distribution in "rugarch"?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, garch, degrees-of-freedom, t-distribution

When I specify a GARCH-model (using "rugarch" package in R) and choose "std" as conditional distribution then the fit gives me a shape parameter. I read both, some say this is equal to DF ([a thread on R-SIG-Finance](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2012q2/010465.html)), some say not.

If I use `rdist` function and plot the density, the higher the shape the fatter the tails, this is not very "std" like. The question is, is the shape equal to "v" in the LogLikelihood formula of [Engle & Bollerslev (1986)](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~boller/Published_Papers/ectrev_86.pdf) p. 35 or is, these days, a completely different formula used for maximum likelihood estimation of GARCH models with "std" error distribution where a shape parameter is included?

Reference:

- Engle, Robert F., and Tim Bollerslev. ["Modelling the persistence of conditional variances."](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~boller/Published_Papers/ectrev_86.pdf) *Econometric Reviews* 5.1 (1986): 1-50.

Comment: *some say not* - could you cite any source?

Comment: Down there in the comments! My Interpretation of it is that it isn't equal...

Comment: <http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201699/degrees-of-freedom-in-t-dist-in-ml-estimation-using-ugarchfit-in-r>

Comment: The d.f. for calculating the AIC or BIC will be simply p + q if the intercept is not included in the model (e.g. because differencing is used) -- can someone confirm this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different objects that can be named *degrees of freedom* in a GARCH model with Student's $t$ errors:

1. The degrees of freedom needed for calculating information criteria such as AIC or BIC is the number of model parameters being estimated, which will be the $1+s+r$ parameters from the conditional variance equation in a GARCH($s,r$) model *plus* the parameter determining the shape of the Student's $t$ distribution, so $1+s+r+1$ in total.
2. The degrees of freedom of the Student's $t$ distribution.

Obviously, 1. does not give the shape parameter of the Student's $t$ distribution.
Meanwhile, 2. does. This is confirmed by [the answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2012q2/010465.html) in R-SIG-Finance list by the author of "rugarch" package (Alexios Ghalanos), and he certainly knows what he is talking about.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that! Really! But I have one further question, I hope it's not too specific, if I model the density of the std (with "rdist"), then the density's peak is very high for a  low shape parameter and it comes down for a higher parameters ( it approaches the normal from above) , but shouldn't a student distribution approach the normal from below, the peak rises with the DF

Comment: @jürgen, Student's $t$ distribution converges to the normal distribution when the degrees of freedom go to infinity. From around d.f.=30 and higher Student's $t$ is really close to normal, but for low d.f. it has much heavier tails than normal. Regarding the peak, what you see from `rdist` is correct.